# How can I log private methods via Spring AOP?

Tags: spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop, aopalliance

I am not able to log the private methods using spring aop performance logging.
Below is the configuration I am using below configuration

```
<aop:config proxy-target-class="true">
        <aop:pointcut id="allServiceMethods" expression="execution(* com.mycom.app.abc..*.*(..))"/>
        <aop:advisor pointcut-ref="allServiceMethods" advice-ref="performanceMonitor" order="2"/>
    </aop:config>
```

I am having `cglib` jar on my class path.

Comment: I am having some nested private method calls and want to log them as well

Comment: I am afraid for nested calls it is a similar problem. The aspect only works when the method is call from outside, I guess because when called internally in the bean the AOP proxy is not used.

Answer (score 11):

You have to use compile time weaving instead of the proxy usage for Spring AOP.

From [Spring AOP - Supported Pointcut Designators](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-pointcuts-designators)

> Due to the proxy-based nature of Spring’s AOP framework, protected methods are by definition not intercepted, neither for JDK proxies (where this isn’t applicable) nor for CGLIB proxies (where this is technically possible but not recommendable for AOP purposes). As a consequence, any given pointcut will be matched against public methods only!
>
> If your interception needs include protected/private methods or even constructors, consider the use of Spring-driven native AspectJ weaving instead of Spring’s proxy-based AOP framework. This constitutes a different mode of AOP usage with different characteristics, so be sure to make yourself familiar with weaving first before making a decision.